# How to disable SIM notification telling you your number?

Tags: notifications, sim-card

When I reboot my phone, I always get this message from Android:

> Your number: +XX XXX XXXX XXXX

I'm on Android 9. How can I disable it? (I'm not changing SIMs or something, just plain reboot.) To clarify, this is not the usual notification that you get from other apps, but a simple popup (from the SIM card I presume). There is only one SIM card slot.

Comment: What do you mean by "get this message"? Is it an Android notification? If yes from which app does it come from? If your device a dual SIM device and do you have two SIM cards inserted?

Comment: @Robert Fixed. No it's from the system and my device only has one SIM card slot.